# Ajax Form Submit not stay on same page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I have designed a Sidebar Floating Form with PhP/Ajax.
Here is the Link: http://logohour.com/form.html
Everything is fine but when a visitor fill and submit the form it routes to anther page for the confirmation.

I am using almost the same coding for clickable form and its working fine but here on this sidebar floating form somewhere I am mistaking may be in Ajax or PHP.

Ajax you may find in Page Source, Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

// Define some constants
define( "RECIPIENT_NAME", "John Smith" );
define( "RECIPIENT_EMAIL", "example@gmail.com" );
define( "EMAIL_SUBJECT", "SiderBar Visitor Message" );

// Read the form values
$ssuccess = false;
$Name = isset( $_POST['Name'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Name'] ) : "";
$Email = isset( $_POST['Email'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Email'] ) : "";
$Phone = isset( $_POST['Phone'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Phone'] ) : "";
$Country = isset( $_POST['Country'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Country'] ) : "";
$Select = isset( $_POST['Select'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['Select'] ) : "";
$Message = isset( $_POST['Message'] ) ? preg_replace( "/(From:|To:|BCC:|CC:|Subject:|Content-Type:)/", "", $_POST['Message'] ) : "";

// If all values exist, send the email
if ( $Name && $Email && $Phone && $Country && $Select && $Message ) {

    $msgToSend = "Name: $Name\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Email: $Email\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Phone: $Phone\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Country: $Country\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Sender Select: $Select\n";
    $msgToSend .= "Message: $Message";

    $recipient = RECIPIENT_NAME . " <" . RECIPIENT_EMAIL . ">";
    $headers = "From: " . $Name . " <" . $Email . ">";
    $ssuccess = mail( $recipient, EMAIL_SUBJECT, $msgToSend, $headers );
}

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
  echo $ssuccess ? "ssuccess" : "error";
} else {
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thanks!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php if ( $ssuccess ) echo "<p>Thanks for sending your message! We'll get back to you shortly.</p>" ?>
  <?php if ( !$ssuccess ) echo "<p>There was a problem sending your message. Please try again.</p>" ?>
  <p>Click your browser's Back button to return to the page.</p>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Here is the AJAX Source Code**

```html
    var messageDDelay = 2000; // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)
    // Init the form once the document is ready
    $(init);
    // Initialize the form
    function init() {
      // Hide the form initially.
      // Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
      // Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.

      // When the "Send us an email" link is clicked:
      // 1. Fade the content out
      // 2. Display the form
      // 3. Move focus to the first field
      // 4. Prevent the link being followed
      $('a[href="#contact_form"]').click(function() {
        $('#content').fadeTo('slow', .2);
        $('#contact_form').fadeIn('slow', function() {
          $('#Name').focus();
        })
        return false;  });
      // When the "Cancel" button is clicked, close the form
      $('#cancel').click(function() {
        $('#contact_form').fadeOut();
        $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);
      });
      // When the "Escape" key is pressed, close the form
      $('#contact_form').keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 27) {
          $('#contact_form').fadeOut();
          $('#content').fadeTo('slow', 1);}});}
    // Submit the form via Ajax
    function submitFForm() {
      var contact_form = $(this);
      // Are all the fields filled in?
      if (!$('#Name').val() || !$('#Email').val() || !$('#Phone').val() || !$('#Country').val() || !$('#Select').val() || !$('#Message').val()) {
        // No; display a warning message and return to the form
        $('#incompleteMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        contact_form.fadeOut().delay(messageDDelay).fadeIn();
      } else {
        // Yes; submit the form to the PHP script via Ajax
        $('#sendingMMessage').fadeIn();
        contact_form.fadeOut();
        $.ajax({
          url: contact_form.attr('action') + "?ajax=true",
          type: contact_form.attr('method'),
          data: contact_form.serialize(),
          ssuccess: submitFFinished        });      }
      // Prevent the default form submission occurring
      return false;    }
    // Handle the Ajax response
    function submitFFinished(response) {
      response = $.trim(response);
      $('#sendingMMessage').fadeOut();
      if (response == "ssuccess") {
        // Form submitted ssuccessfully:
        // 1. Display the ssuccess message
        // 2. Clear the form fields
        // 3. Fade the content back in
        $('#successMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        $('#Name').val("");
        $('#Email').val("");
        $('#Phone').val("");
        $('#Country').val("");
        $('#Selct').val("");
        $('#Message').val("");
        $('#content').delay(messageDDelay + 500).fadeTo('slow', 1);
      } else {
        // Form submission failed: Display the failure message,
        // then redisplay the form
        $('#failureMMessage').fadeIn().delay(messageDDelay).fadeOut();
        $('#contact_form').delay(messageDDelay + 500).fadeIn();      }    }
```

Comment: show your ajax code. it is important and we can not find source code using page source

Comment: you are sending the content of the form using the post methode... When PHP send a response, it replaces the loaded DOM...

Comment: U am not sure if this I understood right. You click on submit and the problem is it redirects you (I tried the page, but nothing happened on submit). If that is the case, this might be of help: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: Alright Now submit button is working but as I said .. as per my coding, on submission it shouldn't route to another page for success it must be on the same page but success message (this is the only problem)

Answer (score 0):

use your function like this:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(submitFForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the submitFForm() function.  Try setting a click event to the submit button or setting the "submit" event to the form, e.g:

```
$("#contact_form").submit(function(e) {
submitFForm();
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but I think you're saying that this code isn't functioning correctly:

```
$('a[href="#contact_form"]').click(function() {
    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', .2);
    $('#contact_form').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $('#Name').focus();
    })
    return false;
});
```

Is that right? If so, try replacing it with this:

```
$('#sendMMessage').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').fadeTo('slow', .2);
    $('#contact_form').fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $('#Name').focus();
    });
    alert('successfully stopped the other page loading');
    return false;
 });
```

Using both `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` is the correct way to stop the expected redirect. Your jQuery selector also needed to be corrected.

Comment: Ok use this website (http://logo.logohour.com/) and if you click on yellow button on slider "Request for Quote" the form open which successful submitted without page change ... I am trying for the same on provided sidebar form.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sendMMessage').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

.... ajax ...etc

})
```

You have to annulate the default submit behaviour.